# 504 Gateway Time-out error in batch process

Tags: 6, batch-operations

I have submit the custom form using **batch process** in which process I have upload big xml file(min 200MB) and read xml file and inserted xml data in database

but after 30~35 minits batch process display the

> 504 Gateway Time-out error.

Also I have increased **memory size**, **excution time**, **max upload size** and so on.

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find the answer...

Please increase memory limit, excution time and max input time.

**1. File php.ini**

```
memory_limit = 768M
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600
```

OR

**Define in settings.php**

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_limit ', '768M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
    ini_set('max_input_time', 3600);    
?>
```

My problem is solve. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Background Process**](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_process) Module

> This modules takes over the existing Batch API and runs batch jobs in
>   a background process. This means that if you leave the batch page, the
>   jobs continues, and you can return to the progress indicator later.
>
> Batch jobs are delegated to the service host "background_batch" if
>   defined